# SelectRow method in MS Project. Works fine in Project VBA, but not in VSTO

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub Select_Row()

 'Activate Gantt Chart
 ViewApply Name:="&Gantt Chart"
 SelectRow Row:=3, RowRelative:=False, Height:=2, Add:=True
End Sub
```

The above subroutine works fine in Project VBA, but when I try the same in VSTO. i get the error `SelectRow is not declared`. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Perhaps you have to make reference for your project. See [this](http://zo-d.com/blog/archives/programming/making-the-move-from-vba-to-vsto-in-microsoft-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the application before ViewApply

I had the same problem and I fixed it like this (I am using the application addin)

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ViewApply(Name:="Name-of-view")

I hope this helps

Med Toledo

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the ProjectApplication object explicitly in VB.Net. In VBA it is 'implied' but you have to be specific in VB.Net